# How secure is the chromium browser compared to chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, chromium

Now that chrome has ended support for 32 bit linux, I was wondering if chromium is as secure and as reliable as chrome. If not what changes can be made to chromeium?

Answer (score 2):

Chromium is almost exactly the same as Chrome - Chrome uses Chromium as a base and adds a few proprietary Google things to it, which can't be added to the open-source Chromium. These are things like the Flash player, PDF viewer, and certain video codecs. See [this Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/chrome/comments/1xsxjv/best_browser_google_chrome_vs_chromium/cfeku0r) for more.

As for 32 vs 64 bit - unless you're using a very old computer, [you should be using a 64 bit operating system](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=ubuntu_1404_x64&num=1).

Comment: About 32bit vs 64bit, 64bit leaves less free ram compared to 32bit, and the extra 5%-10% performance gain in 64bit is irrelevant when my processors are only at 2%-5% capacity almost all the time - I'd much rather have more ram to use.